# How to create a rotate button in shiny uploaded image

Tags: r, shiny

I'm uploading an image in shinyApp and rendering like the code below

```
library(shiny)
library(base64enc)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput("image","Photo"),
  uiOutput("image"),
  actionButton("rotate_image","Rotate")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # check ext
  valid_extensions <- c("png", "jpeg", "jpg")
  
  # update img when change
  base64 <- reactive({
    req(input$image)
    inFile <- input[["image"]]
    if (!is.null(inFile) && tools::file_ext(input$image$name) %in% valid_extensions) {
      dataURI(file = inFile$datapath, mime = "image/png")
    }
  })
  
  # render the uploaded image
  output[["image"]] <- renderUI({
    if (!is.null(base64()) && tools::file_ext(input$image$name) %in% valid_extensions) {
      tags$div(
        tags$img(src = base64()),
      )
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I think I need to `observeEvent(input$rotate_image)` and use something like `magick::image_rotate()` but I can't find any solution.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jQueryRotate](https://jqueryrotate.com/). Download the file **jQueryRotate.js** and put it in the **www** subfolder of your app.

```r
library(shiny)
library(base64enc)

js <- '$("#myimage").rotate({angle:0, animateTo:360});'

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "jQueryRotate.js")
  ),
  br(),
  fileInput("image","Photo"),
  uiOutput("image"),
  br(),
  actionButton("rotate_image", "Rotate", onclick = js)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # check ext
  valid_extensions <- c("png", "jpeg", "jpg")
  
  # update img when change
  base64 <- reactive({
    req(input$image)
    inFile <- input[["image"]]
    if(
      !is.null(inFile) && 
      tools::file_ext(input$image$name) %in% valid_extensions
    ){
      dataURI(file = inFile$datapath, mime = "image/png")
    }
  })
  
  # render the uploaded image
  output[["image"]] <- renderUI({
    if(
      !is.null(base64()) && 
      tools::file_ext(input$image$name) %in% valid_extensions
    ){
      tags$div(
        tags$img(id = "myimage", src = base64(), width = "50%"),
      )
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the fast and really good answer! Nice GIF too. I can't upvote your comment because of my level, but it helped me a lot.